# Generics <? super A> doesn't allow superTypes of A to be added to the list

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am using wildcard and lower bound generics on list and yet compiler is throwing error.

Code:

```
int intStart = 0;       
Number num = new Integer(2);                
List<? super Integer> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
listOfNumbers.add(intStart);
listOfNumbers.add(num); //throws compiler error
```

Error :

> The method add(capture#8-of ? super Integer) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Number)

With `List<? super Integer>`, I should have been allowed to add any objects of type `Integer` or its superTypes e.g. Number or Object.
I've gone through some SO discussions, but couldn't find why I should be getting above error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> With `List<? super Integer>`, I should have been allowed to add any objects of type Integer or its superTypes e.g. Number or Object.

That's incorrect. `List<? super Integer>` doesn't mean *a list that can hold any supertype of Integer*. It means *a list whose generic type may be some **specific** supertype of Integer*. So it might actually be `List<Object>`, `List<Number>` or `List<Integer>`. All of those list types may contain an `Integer`, but the same can't be said for `Number`. A `Number` might be a `Double` or a `Long`, which isn't allowed in a `List<Integer>`.

To make it a little more concrete, consider this snippet:

```
Long longValue = 2L;
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
// listOfIntegers.add(longValue);
```

The commented line obviously shouldn't compile, and doesn't. But what if we added this:

```
Number longAsNumber = longValue;
List<? super Integer> listOfSuper = listOfIntegers;
listOfSuper.add(longAsNumber);
```

This is equivalent to the snippet in your question. Should the final line compile? If it would, it would violate the generic invariant of `List<Integer>`.

---

In response to your comment, `List<? super Integer>` is indeed unnecessary in your example. A more common case would be to add flexibility to a method parameter. For example, a method

```
void addInt(List<Integer> list) {
    list.add(1);
}
```

would only be able to accept `List<Integer>`, which would be unnecessarily restrictive. Changing the parameter type to `List<? super Integer>` would allow the method to accept `List<Integer>` as well as `List<Number>`, either of which can contain an `Integer` value.

This only works if the list is *consuming* the generic type in question. If the method tried to *produce* values from the list, it would be forced to assume they're of type `Object`, since we don't have a definite supertype. For more information, see [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: thx for your answer. Assuming that compiler can't figure out the type of list elements from provided generic parameter type <? super Integer> i.e. list of Integers v/s list of Numbers etc., what would be real world use of such construct if all it does is to allow us to add Integers to the list? Same can also be achieved through List<Integer> varName = new ArrayList<>(); declaration. So, why to use <? super Integer>? I know i am asking questions on my own code, but the intent is to understand the design decisions behind such constructs and its practical use.

Comment: Thanks for the update and especially for the SO thread. It clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

`List<? super Integer>` is a bit weird. You can only add Integers (int gets auto-boxed to Integer). You can't add a Number because that is not allowed in a `List<Integer>`, even though `List<Number>` is a valid assignment to `List<? super Integer>`, because you may be working with a `List<Integer>`. Since the compiler doesn't know for sure, it won't allow the unsafe operation.

So in short, When using a `List<? super Integer>`, The only type safe to read is Object, and the only type safe to write is Integer. The compiler doesn't allow it because it is an unsafe operation.

(For Further reading, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/6893866) gives a pretty good detailed explanation of the generics of this)